# Magento2 : How to change sort by option position in sorting options

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sorting

Native Magento give 3 options position, name, price for sort by option. I added one custom product attribute for sorting option. I want to display it on first position but it is displaying on last position.

How can I change position of custom added attribute and it will display on first sort by option.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes , Native Three Option position, name, price comes and **by default Sort by position  is selected**

[image]

**Added Size** 4th criteria to sort

[image]

Suppose you want to make **Short by Size by default**

Go to below path and **uncheck the USE SYSTEM VALUE** then select your value

`Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Store Front > Product Listing Sort by > size`

[image]

[image]

If you added **custom value that should be here in drop down list** and then you can select that for default shorting via admin

I hope this will help you out, Tested on default LUMA Theme

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's used for default sort by option but not display on first position. I want to display it on first position currently it is showing on fourth position.

Comment: added  Size and its coming on 4th no in drop down, then I selected it in default sorting and it comes sorted by default and show size a default value

Comment: I want display it on first possession

Comment: in drop down you want it at first position ? and i think that is in  alphabetical order

Comment: Yes I want that

Comment: i have similar question, can you take a look?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358299/magento2-4-how-to-sort-products-by-sizes-m-l-xl

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plugins.

For that:

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) you can check how to make a plugin.

1. Make a di.xml file.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
<plugin name="Company_Catalog::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray" type="Company\Catalog\Plugin\AttributeUsedForSortByArray" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

2. Make your plugin file.

*

```
namespace Firstygroup\Catalog\Plugin;

class AttributeUsedForSortByArray
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
        $options,
        $result
    )
    {
        if ($result) {
            if(isset($result['position'])){
                unset($result['position']);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you take a look at my question 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358299/magento2-4-how-to-sort-products-by-sizes-m-l-xl